# Query returns multiple rows for a single count

Tags: sql, oracle, bi-publisher

I have created a query to return number of bank statement lines per day.

For some reason, when there is a statement that has come in, there are two rows of the same bank account name. One row returns 0 for total statement lines and the other returns the correct statement lines number.

If statement lines have not come in for the day, the query only returns one row with 0 as total statement lines which is correct.

Please help.

```
    select  distinct cb.bank_name,
    cba.bank_account_name   Bank_Account_Name,
    cba.bank_account_num    Bank_Account_Number,
    le.name                 Legal_entity_Name,
    (select count(csl1.STATEMENT_LINE_ID)
    from ce_statement_lines csl1
    where to_char(csl1.booking_date,'yyyy/MM/dd') = to_char(:P_Date,'yyyy/MM/dd')
    and csl1.STATEMENT_HEADER_ID = CESL.STATEMENT_HEADER_ID
    --GROUP BY cba.bank_account_id, csl1.STATEMENT_LINE_ID
    ) total_statement_line_for_date 
    from
    ce_bank_accounts cba,
    xle_entity_profiles le,
    CE_STATEMENT_HEADERS CESH,
    ce_banks_v cb,
    ce_statement_lines CESL
    WHERE cba.account_owner_org_id  = le.legal_entity_id
    and cb.bank_party_id            = cba.bank_id
    and cba.bank_account_id = CESH.BANK_ACCOUNT_ID
    and CESL.STATEMENT_HEADER_ID = CESH.STATEMENT_HEADER_ID
   -- GROUP BY cb.bank_name, cba.bank_account_name, cba.bank_account_num, le.name, cba.bank_account_id
    order by cba.bank_account_name

|----------------|------------------|------------------ |-------|------|
|    Bank Name   |Bank Account Name |Bank Account Number|LE Name| Count|
|----------------|------------------|-------------------|-------|------|
|     A Name     |  A Account Name  |  A Account Number | A LE  |   0  |
|----------------|------------------|-------------------|-------|------|
|     B Name     |  B Account Name  |  B Account Number | B LE  |   0  |
|----------------|------------------|-------------------|-------|------|
|     B Name     |  B Account Name  |  B Account Number | B LE  |  17  |
|----------------|------------------|-------------------|-------|------|
|     C Name     |  C Account Name  |  C Account Number | C LE  |   0  |
|----------------|------------------|-------------------|-------|------|
|     C Name     |  C Account Name  |  C Account Number | C LE  |   1  |
|----------------|------------------|-------------------|-------|------|
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd prefer sample data, but - if you are satisfied with the current query and it does what you want it to but would also want to get rid of the `count = 0` rows if there are rows whose `count` values aren't `0`, then a simple option is

```
SQL> with test (account_num, le_name, cnt) as
  2  -- this represents result of your current query
  3    (select 'A', 'A LE',  0 from dual union all
  4     select 'B', 'B LE',  0 from dual union all
  5     select 'B', 'B LE', 17 from dual union all
  6     select 'C', 'C LE',  0 from dual union all
  7     select 'C', 'C LE',  1 from dual
  8    )
  9  -- query you might need
 10  select account_num,
 11         le_name,
 12         sum(cnt) cnt
 13  from test
 14  group by account_num,
 15           le_name
 16  order by account_num;

A LE_NAME          CNT
- --------- ----------
A A LE               0
B B LE              17
C C LE               1

SQL>
```

Comment: Hi Littlefoot, is there a way to be able to keep the rows that only result in a single 0 for a single bank account. I only want to remove the 0's where there is a duplicate account number?

Comment: Probably. I can't tell because "output" you posted is so generic that I can't distinguish what is what.

Comment: so the A account did not have any statements come in today so therefore will show a 0. This row is correct. Accounts B contained 17 transactions in the statement today and account C contained 1. However I have additional rows for B and C which output 0 but this is not correct. Thanks for your help

Comment: Aha, OK; got it now, thank you. In that case, you might use something like my example shows; have a look, please. Lines #1 - 8 represent your current query. Line #12 sums `count` column values which means that it'll return result you want, and - if there are more than 2 "same" rows (with different `count` value), it should still be OK.